# Add a language to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I installed Visual Studio 2013 Community edition with C++. Now I want to use it to program in C#. The problem is VS will not let me create C# files, only C++ files. How do I correct this?

Bonus points if you can answer this question: Why does Google provide no relevant results when I try and search for it in several different wordings?

Comment: Have you created a C# project?

Comment: @stuartd Yes. No .cs files can be made.

Comment: So when you right click on the project and choose, say "Add Class", what happens?

Comment: @stuartd I can't tell you right away, the VS installer is running a repair install because I got desperate. I don't think I had that option to begin with though.

Comment: When creating a new project, were there any options on the left-hand side to choose a different language, as described [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/create-your-app-vs)?